# How to add a constraint with superscript and a union in the domain?

Tags: constraints, jupyter, union, superscript

I want to add a constraint in jupyter but I don't know how to add a superscript and how I can add a union in the constraint. This is the constraint I want to add:
[constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5582.png)

And this is how I add it in jupyter. It still needs the superscripts and the union:

```
con4 = {}
for i in P:
    for k in K:
         con4[i,j] = m.addConstr((sum(x[j,i] for j in N) - sum(x[i,j] for j in N)) == 0,  'con1['+ str(i) + str(j) + ']-')
```

Comment: This question lacks context.  What are `m`, `x`, `P`,`K`, etc?  `jupyter` just identifies the programming environment, not even the language (python?) or import modules.

Comment: k is the number of a vehicle in set K. P is the set of pick up nodes. So the only thing I want to know is how to put the formula into code (jupyter).